# How can we add a temporary dependency when running "mvn install" from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, maven, command-line

I cannot run my application on my machine unless I add a dependency. Since this is only a hotfix, I do not want to add the dependency on the git repo.

I would like a way to add a temporary dependency, without having to edit the pom.xml everytime I git pull/push.

Comment: If the app does not work without the dependency then add it to the pom file and commit it..A temporary dependency sounds really strange ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using maven profiles.
Just put the dependency that is required only for hotfix on the profile named hotfix and put other dependencies without any profile.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>hotfix</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>…</dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>...</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To activate the profile supply profile name with -P option on any maven command.
For example, to activate hotfix profile while doing clean and install use command
mvn clean install -Photfix

Also, there are other ways to activate maven profiles.
Please see link for more information: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html